# Java: get substring from an string without lang3 utils and StringUtils

Tags: java

I need to get a integer from a string **using Java 7**.

String is something like:

```
"\"Transformed\": any-number,
```

I need to get `any-number` substring after first match of `\"Transformed\":` string.

Comment: What did you try so far? This looks like JSON, did you try parsing that?

Comment: This is likely best solved using *regular expression*. If you don't know *regex*, now is a great time to learn. --- Unless it's JSON, then it's best solved using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been advised in the comments, if it is a JSON it is more appropriate to use JSON parser. Otherwise you can use regex which might look similar to this:

```
String line = "\"Transformed\": 10";
String pattern = "Transformed.:.(\\d+)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
}else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH");
}
```

You can find more info about current regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/u0zaBM/1). Please note that this is the simplest case possible and you will probably have to update it, depending on the string format.